# After successfully digital sign of wix bootstrapper output .exe is not installing

Tags: wix, installation, sign, bootstrapper

If try to install without digital sign of bootstrapper output .exe file, it's working fine.But after digital sign installer show an error. [image]

to sign .exe, used bellow code in bootstrap.wixproj file before the closing /Project tag.

```
    <!-- SignOutput must be present in some PropertyGroup to trigger signing. -->
  <PropertyGroup> 
    <SignOutput>true</SignOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>

   <!-- Sign the bundle engine -->
  <Target Name="SignBundleEngine">
    <Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce\SignTool\signtool.exe&quot; sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha512 /fd sha512 /f &quot;D:\Digital Sign Resorce\CARoot.pfx&quot; /p Test123 /d &quot;My Project Name&quot; &quot;D:\Project\xxx\v3.2.0.0\SetupWiX\bin\Release\SetupWiX.msi&quot;" />
  </Target>

  <!-- Sign the final bundle -->
  <Target Name="SignBundle">
    <Exec Command="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce\SignTool\signtool.exe&quot; sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha512 /fd sha512 /f &quot;D:\Digital Sign Resorce\CARoot.pfx&quot; /p Test123 /d &quot;My Project Name&quot; &quot;D:\Project\xxx\v3.2.0.0\Bootstrapper_New\bin\Release\MyApp.exe&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what works for me. I install the certificate (and only one certificate) in the personal store of my build user service account so that it's auto selected without a passphrase or access to the PFX file elsewhere. My MSI is already signed in a previous build step.

```
  <Target Name="SignBundleEngine">
    <Exec Command="signtool.exe sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com &quot;@(SignBundleEngine)&quot;" />
    <Exec Command="Signtool.exe sign /fd SHA256 /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 &quot;@(SignBundleEngine)&quot;" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="SignBundle">
    <Exec Command="signtool.exe sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com &quot;@(SignBundle)&quot;" />
    <Exec Command="Signtool.exe sign /fd SHA256 /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 &quot;@(SignBundle)&quot;" />
  </Target>
```